# About using scala def apply method

Tags: scala

```
val B = new {
  def apply : { val a : Int } => { val b : String ; val c : Int } =
    x => new { val b = "Hi" ; val c = 0 }
}
```

I can't understand this code.
What does it doing?
And how can I use apply of B. It seems B doesn't have b or c..

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile. It isn't clear what you want to do.

Comment: Does compile with 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiles just fine here.

```
scala> val B = new {
    |   def apply : { val a : Int } => { val b : String ; val c : Int } =
    |     x => new { val b = "Hi" ; val c = 0 }
    | }
B: AnyRef{def apply: AnyRef{val a: Int} => AnyRef{val b: String; val c: Int}} = $anon$1@464bee09
```

The signature is quite clear, however something you'll have to get used to.

```
AnyRef
```

an anonymous object. Similar to java Object

```
  {def apply: AnyRef{val a: Int} => AnyRef{val b: String; val c: Int}}
```

however, you still have the signature available via structural typing. I
normally wouldn't recommend that, it uses reflection at runtime, which makes the
method call a bit slow.

```
  def apply: AnyRef{val a: Int} => AnyRef{val b: String; val c: Int}
```

It returns a `=>`, also known as `Function1`, which is short for a function
object that takes one argument. Here it takes an argument of type `AnyRef{val a:
Int}` and returns an object of type `AnyRef{val b: String; val c: Int}`.

The same comment as above applies for the structural typing nature.

How I would recommend writing this code:

```
case class Foo(b: String, c: Int)
val B: Int => Foo = { x => Foo("Hi", 0) }
```

Comment: _"an anonymous object"_: isn't it rather an object based on an anonymous type declaration?

Comment: How are the two different?

Comment: "anonymous object" implies that the object doesn't have a name. That information is redundant. Only methods, packages, package objects, traits, classes, and singleton `object`s have names, "regular" objects never have names, so they are always anonymous.